# Does decellularization with sodium lauryl sulfate break down enzymes?

Tags: cell-biology, cell-culture

I am currently looking into decellularization with sodium lauryl sulfate since it is effective and cheap. My goal is to break down the cells of a plant leaf and release the chloroplasts to be viewed under a microscope(I realize you can do this without decellularization but I'm still curious). My question is, will sodium lauryl sulfate break down the cell membrane and cause no further damage to the organelles or enzymes? If not, what chemicals can break the cell membrane without causing any more damage to the organelles or enzymes?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please take a [tour] and visit the [help] for more information about this Stack and what we do here. In addition please note the [homework policy](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework), which generally asks that the person asking the question demonstrates what they know about their question. So... what do you know about SDS/SLS and its chemistry?